the shacdn/ui install command not intepret @ correctly to /src
i want to ask and i need help with this
i tried to follow the documentations of the latest shacn/ui using vite
but when i ran this command npx shadcn-ui@latest init
it seems not installing components and lib files in ./src folder instead it keeps creating new folder named "@" in root folder
while my vite.config.ts is already correctly alias @ as /src as in the documentation

vite.config.ts

import path from "path"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
})


here is also the tsconfig.app.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}


i have no idea why it keeps creating @ folder at root directory. i just assumed for now the shadcn/ui not intepreting @ correctly as /src
so i have to manually set the components.json to src folder like this bellow :
{
  "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
  "style": "new-york",
  "rsc": false,
  "tsx": true,
  "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.js",
    "css": "src/global.css",
    "baseColor": "slate",
    "cssVariables": true,
    "prefix": ""
  },
  "aliases": {
***    "components": "src/components",
    "utils": "/src/lib/utils"***
  }
}

any help is very much appreciated
the shacdn/ui is not correctly interpret @ to src folder
